# How do I get "table view" working for CSV data in PyCharm?

Tags: csv, ide, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I used to able to rely on the ability to edit CSV data in PyCharm (and other JetBrains IDEs) in a [fully functional tabular view](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/editing-csv-files.html):

[image]

however I can't find this functionality anywhere in my current version (5.0.x).

How do I get this functionality back?

---

Note that it appears that I can right click on the selected text of the CSV and choose something called (incorrectly and misleadingly) "Edit as Table..."; but this can't be intended as a replacement for the missing functionality!

Answer (score 7):

According to the PyCharm [Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/editing-csv-and-similar-files-in-table-format.html):

> For the table editor and associated features to be available:
>
> - You should be using the **Professional Edition of PyCharm.** (The corresponding functionality is not available in the Community Edition.)
> - The Database Tools and SQL **plugin** must be enabled. (This plugin is bundled with the IDE and enabled by default.)
> - The file name extension must be associated with the **text file** type. See e.g. File Types.

I use  Professional Edition, so im my case, the issues was in missing association of file type. I fix it next:

1. Go to `File | Settings | Editor | File Types
2. Find **Text** file type
3. Add `*.csv` to the Text file type.
4. Save end exit

Comment: The relevant [PyCharm 2017.3 help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/editing-csv-and-other-delimiter-separated-files-as-tables.html) has the same prerequisites but it seems to work even without adding to the Text file type. It'd be really nice to not have to invoke the "Edit as Table..." manually each time you open a file.

Comment: In PyCharm 2022.3.3 (and probably later, I've been slow to update on the computer I'm currently using) you can add `*.csv` to the `CSV/TSV data` entry under `File Types`.

Answer (score 3):

Please vote for [DBE-1845](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-1845) to be notified on any progress. As a temporary workaround you can try assigning a keyboard shortcut to  "`Edit as Table...`" action as suggested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-1845#comment=27-1193834

Comment: Yes, As indicated I know about "Edit as Table..." That can't be the intended solution, can it? That leads to a useless and dysfunctional UI. I guess this means JetBrains really did remove this feature and that until it's restored one must just use an external third-party CSV editor. (That's an answer I'd accept.)

Comment: As this question is about PyCharm, the link to PHPStorm may not be the best fit.  Here's the same bug for PyCharm to vote on: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11840

Comment: The link is to DBE, not PHPStorm. DBE is a host project for database support, and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-1845 is the correct ticket. The PyCharm bug mentioned by you was fixed as far back as in PyCharm 133.* and is now obsolete. And it has absolutely no relation to current issue

Comment: BTW, was it you who downvoted my answer? What's the reason for that?

Comment: Your answer had a -1 score when i found this SO page.  I did not downvote it.  Viewing a CSV file is not the same as a database table, so the link you shared still doesn't seem to be a perfect fit (while it may be the best fit available). The issue i linked to, while obsolete, does represent a PyCharm-specific issue, and an additional link to the incorrect documentation which should be updated: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/editing-csv-files.html#d60551e451

Answer (score 0):

Although Table view works for csv files in PyCharm ( if you have the Professional Edition of PyCharm and Tools and SQL plugin  is enabled (which is by default), it does not appear in the right click menu!

A good way to solve this is to create a shortcut for "Table view"! then just select your text and press that shortcut key.